# Get friend list of facebook login user using FacebookSDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I want to access friend list and their profile picture using FacebookSDK in my iphone application.
Please suggest a demo or code.

Comment: FYI:Try to write some code.. and if u facing any problem, ask that as a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                              NSDictionary* result,
                              NSError *error) {
NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
    NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.id);
}
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                                  NSDictionary* result,
                                                                  NSError *error) {

            NSArray        *data_array = [result objectForKey:@"data"]; //array of friends
            NSMutableArray *pictures = [NSMutableArray array]; // array for pictures               

            for (NSDictionary *friend in data_array)
            {
                NSString *friend_id = friend[@"id"];
                NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture",friend_id];
                NSURL    *url       = [NSURL urlWithString:urlString];
               [pictures addObject:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];

            }
        }];
```

Since `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]` is pretty slow you may consider running this code in background

Answer (score 0):

You need to use FBRequest, requestForMyFriends method it creates a request representing a Graph API call to the "me/friends" endpoint using the active session.

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                              NSDictionary* result,
                              NSError *error) {
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
        NSLog(@"My friend named %@ and id %@", friend.name, friend.id);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"user_birthday",@"friends_hometown",
                        @"friends_birthday",@"friends_location",
                        nil];
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:write handler code..]
```